# Read Message from Error Message Dialog Box using WScript

Tags: vbscript, wsh

Problem Definition : Write wscript to click "OK" button of a Error Message DialogBox and get/read what the Error message is given in the DialogBox.
Error Message is generated from validation of Excel through Macro.

Achieved: I am able to click "OK" button of msgbox

Stuck: I am not able to read the Error Message

Code Written:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

Do 
    bResult = oShell.AppActivate("Save As") 
    If bResult = True Then 
        oShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}" 
        Exit Do 
    End If 
    WScript.Sleep 500 
Loop
```

Comment: Please provide the line of VBA code which shows the message. Is that `MsgBox` function? Do you have an access to VBA code, and able to modify it?